# How should I slice buttons for ios development

Tags: ios, iphone, psd

I'm going to slice a given image for iPhone developer. Since I'm a front-end developer and know that this button can be created using CSS in front-end development, I don't have any idea about how should I proceed. May I give PSDs directly to the developer or should it be sliced? If it should be sliced then how will it be? Here is the image:

[image: Image to be sliced]

Please note that this button has gradient, rounded corners and a little downward arrow. Forget the text inside for now.

Have iPhone developers the ability to do that type of stuff using their code?

If I should export those buttons (eliminating the text/icon inside), at what resolutions should that be?

Comment: Have you tried asking your iphone Developer directly? He may have a preference. This can be replicated through iOS code, but some of it is more of a pain than others (especially the downward arrow). For buttons like this, it's easier to simply have each button as a flat image with 2x and 3x included (with the text + icons). If it has to scale to different screen sizes or if they grow for different scenarios, then flat images aren't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of creating custom reusable UI elements in iOS:

1. styling the [existing properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW59)
2. using [resizable images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ResizableImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH30-SW1)
3. [custom drawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

Definitely ask the developer what they would like since the project may already have something in place or a preference.

If you're using images you'll need to send different sizes for the various pixel densities of the devices: original, 2x, 3x. Also with images you will need to make sure they are [designed to scale properly](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/) when exporting them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've another problem as well. 
My developer is asking me to create annotations for every screen something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxpz2z38v3iwh7d/02.png?dl=0

Is that a normal practice in iphone development?

Also, some images (like car and sender / receiver's photos) are used there. Should I also export those images in highest resolution?

Comment: Annotations will make his life a lot easier, otherwise the developer will have to measure everything by hand which can be a very time consuming process. As far as the fonts go I usually ask the designer to come up with a style guide sort of like a CSS stylesheet so I can reuse the fonts/colors/sizes throughout the app.

Comment: One more thing to consider is if the app will be using auto-layout for different devices sizes. A  recent project I was working on needed certain elements larger/smaller for different devices. In that case the designer should start designing from the smallest screen size to the largest. With auto-layout UI element sizes can be hardcoded to specific values or based on percentages. This all depends on the requirements.